# Can a Thunderbolt cable be "TB3" is it doesn't support 40GB/s

Tags: usb, speed, thunderbolt, usb-c

As I understood, thunderbolt 3 specs include a bitrate of 40Gb/s. How can this startech cable be TB3 if it's only 20Gb/s ?

https://www.startech.com/be/nl/Kabels/thunderbolt-3-kabels/thunderbolt-3-20gbps-usb-c-kabel~TBLT3MM2M

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thunderbolt_(interface)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a passive Thunderbolt 3 cable, which means it is limited to 20 GBit/s (except for very short cables). Only with active cables can you achieve the maximum speed of 40 GBit/s.

Active cables are much more expensive. They are different internally from passive cables and cannot be used for USB 3.1 Gen1/2 for example but only USB 2.0. They also do not support DisplayPort signals directly (only wrapped within Thunderbolt).

Wikipedia offers a better table on the [USB-C article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB-C#Alternate_Mode_partner_specifications):

```
+=============+=================================================================+=============================================================+==============+
|             |                               USB 3.1 Type-C cable              |                  Adapter cable or adapter                   |              |
|    Mode     | USB | DisplayPort | Thunderbolt           | superMHL | HDMI     | HDMI        | DVI-D                    | Component video    | Construction |
|             | 3.1 | 1.2   | 1.4 | 20 Gbit/s | 40 Gbit/s |          | 1.4b     | 1.4b | 2.0b | single-link | dual-link  | (YPbPr, VGA/DVI-A) |              |
+=============+=====+=======+=====+===========+===========+==========+==========+======+======+=============+============+====================+==============+
| DisplayPort | Yes | Yes         |                                             | No                                                          | Passive      |
|             +-----+-------------+                                             +-------------+--------------------------+--------------------+--------------+
|             |     | Optional    |                                             | Yes         | Yes                      | Yes                |       Active |
+-------------+-----+-------------+-----------+-----------+---------------------+-------------+--------------------------+--------------------+--------------+
| Thunderbolt | Yes | Yes         | Yes       | Yes [d]   |                     | No                                                          | Passive      |
|             +-----+-------------+-----------+-----------+                     +-------------+--------------------------+--------------------+--------------+
|             |     | Optional    | Optional  | Yes       |                     | Yes         | Yes                      | Yes                |       Active |
+-------------+-----+-------------+-----------+-----------+----------+----------+------+------+-------------+------------+--------------------+--------------+
| MHL         | Yes |                                     | Yes      |          | Yes  | No   | Yes         | No         | No                 | Passive      |
|             +-----+                                     +----------+          +------+------+-------------+------------+--------------------+--------------+
|             |     |                                     | Optional |          |      | Yes  |                          | Yes                |       Active |
+-------------+-----+-------------------------------------+----------+----------+------+------+-------------+------------+--------------------+--------------+
| HDMI        |                                                      | Yes      | Yes  | No   | Yes         | No         | No                 | Passive      |
|             |                                                      +----------+------+------+-------------+------------+--------------------+--------------+
|             |                                                      | Optional |                                        | Yes                |       Active |
+-------------+------------------------------------------------------+----------+----------------------------------------+--------------------+--------------+
```

...where note d is: “Thunderbolt 3 40 Gbit/s passive cables are only possible <0.5 m due to limitations of current cable technology.”

Comment: So, this would then be an active cable as it's 0.8m or did apple stretch the limits (as it also supports USB3.1 Gen2) ? https://www.apple.com/ie/shop/product/MQ4H2ZM/A/thunderbolt-3-usb%E2%80%91c-cable-08-m

Comment: Well, maybe Apple is very confident in its cable making abilities. The 0.5m limit mentioned by Wikipedia is somewhat arbitrary anyway. It’s limited by the electrical characteristics of the cable. At this price, it’s certainly not active.